# Как прикрепить interface к фрагменту, Kotlin, Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Я хочу сделать Attach интерфейса, но я знаю только один способ это сделать:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        try {
            myInterface=context as MyInterface
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.d("myLog",e.message)
        }
    }
```

Но в таком случае интерфейсом можно пользоваться только в Main Activity. А мне надо использовать его в ViewModel. Вопрос: Как это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю что тогда вам просто проще эту самую ViewModel использовать в фрагменте, чем городить какие-то костыли с прокидыванием интерфейса.

Если же вам нужна ViewModel которая будет привязана к ЖЦ активити то вы можете создать sharedViewModel. Сделать это можно тремя способами:

**Нативными средствами kotlin:**

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selected = MutableLiveData<Item>()

    fun select(item: Item) {
        selected.value = item
    }
}

class MasterFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var itemSelector: Selector

    private lateinit var model: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        model = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        } : throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener { item ->
            // Update the UI
        }
    }
}

class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var model: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        model = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
        model.selected.observe(this, Observer<Item> { item ->
            // Update the UI
        })
    }
}
```

**Использовать Koin:**

```
class WeatherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    /*
     * Declare WeatherViewModel with Koin and allow constructor dependency injection
     */
    private val weatherViewModel by viewModel<WeatherViewModel>()
}

class WeatherHeaderFragment : Fragment() {

    /*
     * Declare shared WeatherViewModel with WeatherActivity
     */
    private val weatherViewModel by sharedViewModel<WeatherViewModel>()
}

class WeatherListFragment : Fragment() {

    /*
     * Declare shared WeatherViewModel with WeatherActivity
     */
    private val weatherViewModel by sharedViewModel<WeatherViewModel>()
}
```

Есть так же решение с дагером, ном там более сложное, не буду тут описывать т.к. оно слишком объемное.

Почитать про это можете здесь:

- [Нативные средства](https://blog.mindorks.com/shared-viewmodel-in-android-shared-between-fragments)
- [Koin](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/koin-projects/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel.md)
- [Dagger](https://medium.com/swlh/android-shared-view-model-dagger-espresso-cf1272731535)